# Basic multivariate calculus question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose we have a function of 3 variables, a, b, and c, f(a(x,y,z), b(x,y,z), c(x,y,z)). a, b, and c are each functions of x, y, z.

If I wanted the partial derivative of f with respect to x, would it be the following:

(∂f/∂a)*(∂a/∂x) + (∂f/∂b)*(∂b/∂x) + (∂f/∂c)*(∂c/∂x)

Answer (score 1):

That's right. There are several different notations for this scenario (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Multivariable_case) for example), but the end result is the same, and it's what you had indicated.

Comment: Greatly appreciated. Thank you.